# Error while voting and switching pages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

When I vote on a question or answer and then quickly (within 1-1.5 seconds) switch pages, I often receive "An Error Has Occurred, Please Retry Your Request". If I revisit the page, sometimes my vote shows up, other times it doesn't. This error is hard to reproduce and because I'm always navigating away from the pages I'm not able to inspect the code of the popover box, which I've read here (on meta) contains error information.

I'm using Mac OS Lion and Mac mini with Google Chrome.

Is this a known issue or browser/OS specific problem?

Comment: I have experienced this with Safari on Mac, and Firefox on Win 7. I'm not sure whether this can be solved. I think the box is trigger when the AJAX request fail/cancelled. When you navigate away from the page, the AJAX request might have sent out (and arrive at the server successfully), and the browser will stop listening to response, which will cause the AJAX to fail and trigger the box.

Comment: I've seen that too. Mostly from work, using Chrome and Win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom line: don't do it or just ignore it.

If the AJAX request was already sent to the server, chances are your vote got recorded. However, when you visit another page, the AJAX *response* is going to fail if it hasn't already been received and cause that box to appear. 1 - 1.5 seconds seems like a long time, I usually only get that error if it's less than a second between voting and switching pages.

There's no way to prevent that aside from forcing you to remain on the page until the response is received, and I'm fairly sure people don't want that to happen, and also isn't possible since it can be easily avoided with a little unicorn magic on the client's side. The only plausible solution is to just disable the notification altogether if the user decides to leave the page (I think that's possible).

If I throw a ball into a bucket and then leave, chances are the ball is going to stay in the bucket, but there is still a slight chance the ball will bounce out of the bucket, or maybe the bucket will tip over. Who knows, I didn't stay to see what happened.